# Data fetched from JSON not getting updated

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Below is the script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON('table.json', function (data) {
        $('#mytable').empty();
        var html = '';
        html += '<tr class="tableheader"><th>Name</th><th>Code</th><th>Value</th><th>Bid</th><th>Offer</th></tr>';
        for (var i = 0, size = data.length; i < size; i++) {
            html += '<tr class="tablecontent"><td>' + data[i].name + '</td><td>' + data[i].code + '</td><td>' + data[i].value + '</td><td>' + data[i].bid + '</td><td>' + data[i].offer + '</td></tr>';
        }
        $('#mytable').append(html);
        tablerows('mytable');
        setTimeout(poll, 5000);
    });
});
var poll = function () {
    alert("poll");
    $.getJSON('dummy.json', function (data) {
        setTimeout(poll, 5000);
    });
}
```

I want to update my data. The `poll` function is getting called after every 5 seconds which I checked through the `alert`. But data is not getting updated. Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Inline HTML creation is bad - look into micro-templating. Polling is bad as well, look into comet / websockets.

Comment: Do yourself a favor, and don't use `alert()` for verification. Find your browser's developer console, and use `console.log()` or the other `console` tools. Then you can `console.log(data)`, and you'll be able to see what the problem is.

Comment: in poll function you aren't changing anything, how can you know if the data is not getting updated?

Comment: It looks like you're not calling the function to update your data more than once.  You call `table.json` the first time and update your table, and on subsequent instances you call `dummy.json` and don't do anything with the returned data.

Comment: @nuclearGhost.. i am not able to understand.first m calling table.json which is returning me data. Next time im calling dummy.json. after that what i am supposed to do?

Answer (score 1):

getJSON is a GET request so it will be cached. Set the proper no cache headers on the server.

Also look at your code, you are never processing the data

```
var poll = function () {
    alert("poll");
    $.getJSON('dummy.json', function (data) {
        setTimeout(poll, 5000);  //<--where is the processing you do nothing with the response???
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
       // make the initial JSON request
    $.getJSON('table.json', init)
});

function poll() {
       // make the subsequent JSON requests
    $.getJSON('dummy.json', update);
}

function init(data) {
    $('#mytable').empty();
    var html = '';
    html += '<tr class="tableheader"><th>Name</th><th>Code</th><th>Value</th><th>Bid</th><th>Offer</th></tr>';
    for (var i = 0, size = data.length; i < size; i++) {
        html += '<tr class="tablecontent"><td>' + data[i].name + '</td><td>' + data[i].code + '</td><td>' + data[i].value + '</td><td>' + data[i].bid + '</td><td>' + data[i].offer + '</td></tr>';
    }
    $('#mytable').append(html);
    tablerows('mytable');
    setTimeout(poll, 5000);
}

function update(data) {
    var rows = $("#mytable tr.tablecontent").toArray();
    for (var i = 0, size = data.length; i < size; i++) {
        if (rows[i])
            rows[i].cells[3].firstChild.data = data[i].bid;
    }
    setTimeout(poll, 5000);
}
```

---

Here's the `update` function with more jQuery:

```
function update(data) {
    $("#mytable tr.tablecontent > td:nth-child(4)")
         .slice(0, data.length)
         .text(function(i) {
             return data[i].bid;
          });
    setTimeout(poll, 5000);
}
```

Comment: @epascarello: I originally had `.ready(poll)`, but then noticed that the URL for the `getJSON` request is different. As an alternative, I could have `poll` take the `url` as an argument.

Comment: Ah, I did not spot the different URL, I am betting typo from the OP.

Comment: Thanks user1689607. but with this the whole data is getting replaced with the new json. i want few entries to be updated.

Comment: @user1814044: So you want the new rows to be added to the table every interval, but leave the previous ones in place? I'll update.

Comment: ...or are you saying that you want to keep the rows, but just add the new data?

Comment: @ user1689607 - i am saying like currently i have my bid value as 100. which after 5 seconds should be updated to 110. the rest data is same.

Comment: @user1814044: Then you need to create a function that finds the proper element in the row and updates it.